# Как получить из ObservableCollection последние 10 элементов , а потом при обновление следующие?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

Вот мой код:

```
private ObservableCollection<ChatModel> messageList = new ObservableCollection<ChatModel>();
 public ObservableCollection<ChatModel> MessageList
        {
            get { return messageList; }
            set
            {
                if (messageList != value)
                {
                    messageList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MessageList");
                }
            }
        }
```

есть коллекция в `viewModel`, которая привязана к `listView`, я получаю с сервера данные:

```
MessageList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ChatModel>>(ValueJobject);
```

я делаю мессенджер. В данный момент я в список получаю все элементы(Сообщения) и эти все элементы выгружаются в ListView , я пытаюсь из всей коллекции выводить в ListView, не все сообщения!!! а последние 5 и при свайпе вверх (якобы обновить список сообщений , как во многих мессенджерах) отображать старые сообщения

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Возможно, есть смысл вопрос переформулировать

Comment: Вот теперь напишите в пост то, что вы мне в комментариях написали, а я то не угадал, что вам нужно.

Comment: @tym32167 , я делаю мессенджер. В данный момент я в список получаю все элементы(Сообщения) и эти все элементы выгружаются в ListView , я пытаюсь из всей коллекции выводить в ListView, не все сообщения!!! а последние 5 и при свайпе вверх (якобы обновить список сообщений , как во многих мессенджерах) отображать старые сообщения

Comment: можно использовать методы Take() и Skip(), ObservableCollection позволяет

Comment: @Lenz  я создал еще два списка , в итоге у меня 3 списка (Основной в котором у меня все сообщения), Буферный в котором я временно храню 20 сообщений и тот который я показываю в ListView пользователю